# iOS - Dynamic Label Size Not Returning Properly

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios5

I have spent hours trying to solve this to no success.

I am trying to display data on a UITableViewCell in a way that the height gets dynamically adjusted according to the data.

Now, the apps seems to work fine with a lot of data but with some data, the label doesn't adjust properly. As you can see, the constrainedToSize functionality has been used which returns the height of the given text.

This height is given out incorrectly a lot of times. For example. When the label text is "High - pulsing white, on glidepath - steady white, slightly below glide   slope steady red, low - pulsing red." the returned height is 63 when it should be more than that.

Another example: 
"High - pulsing white, on course and on glidepath - steady white, off course but    on glidepath - pulsing white and red; low - pulsing red" returns the total label height as 84 when it should be more than that as the label doesn't fit on my tableview at all.

A strange thing that I noticed is that the cells that are out of whack usually have sizes 63 or 84... I haven't come across more such sizes but if that could help..

The code:

```
if (tableView.tag ==1) {
    NSString *cellText;
    if ([multipleAddressSplit count]==0) {

        if (indexPath.row ==0) {

            cellText =[OptionText1 objectAtIndex:i];
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {

            cellText =[OptionText2 objectAtIndex:i];

        }
        if (indexPath.row == 2) {

            cellText =[OptionText3 objectAtIndex:i];

        }
    }


    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(OptionTable.frame.size.width , MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    NSLog(@"========start=========");
    NSLog(@"Celltext is: %@",cellText);
    NSLog(@"Method Label %f",(labelSize.height));
    NSLog(@" 1/3rd %f",(OptionTable.frame.size.height/3-15));
    NSLog(@"=========stop========");


    if ((labelSize.height)<((OptionTable.frame.size.height/3)-15)) {
        NSLog(@" Returned 1/3rd is: %f",(OptionTable.frame.size.height/3));

        return (OptionTable.frame.size.height/3);
    }

    else {
        return labelSize.height + 15;

    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is your labels that are too short and not the actual cells?  If the label is 84 points high and the cell is only 50 (for example) it will look strange.  How are you giving the cell height?  I assume you are not because you can't change the height of a cell dynamically like this.  You need to calculate all the cell heights ahead of time (with the delegate method heightForCellAt...)

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically size just the label or the whole cell?  And will the data change in the labels after table creation, or does the data stay static after creation?

Comment: The data stays static, the code that I provided is from the "heightForRowAtIndexPath" delegate method itself. I am calculating the heights before hand and even then I am facing this error.

A lot of times, about similar amounts of data shows a lot of difference when I print their CGSizes. I am so stuck here.. been trying to solve this from past so many days now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was very simple and trivial.

I was taking the width of the LabelSize equal to the width of the cell whereas the textLabel in real is about 10 pixels off from each side. Subtracting 20 pixels from the height fixed the issue.

Thanks for the answers, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In the delegate method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *strIden = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strIden];
         if(cell==nil){
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1

                reuseIdentifier:strIden] autorelease];
         }
}
```

Make different cell ID.

Comment: Doesn't help. I am still getting messed up text. The problem is, the label size is calculated incorrectly. If I get to find the solution to that, the problem will go away for sure.